# How to set maximumFractionDigits in swift 3 with NumberFormatter()

Tags: swift3, nsnumberformatter

I've been reading the Apple Developer Documentation and it appears that it's not updated for the class `NumberFormatter`, they say it swapped from `NSNumberFormatter` to just `NumberFormatter`.

I've found a few examples of functionalities of this class in Swift 3 but I couldn't find how to set the `maximumFractionDigits`.

When I have a Double like this 0.123456789, I'd like to convert it into a String with just 4 fractional digits for example, like this 0.1234.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want it to round up, but rather always round down, use `.floor` or `.down`:

```
let foo = 0.123456789
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 4
formatter.roundingMode = .down
let string = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: foo))
```

If you want the traditional rounding format, just omit the `.roundingMode`, and this will result in `"0.1235"`.

For more information, see the [`NumberFormatter` reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/numberformatter) documentation.